# c++ cast member pointer of derived Class to base class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-pointers

I'm currently working on a HttpServer and have the following problem:

I want to register my controllers and when I get a request I want to check if one of those controllers has a handler for the requested URL and then call the handler.

So far so good, but I don't know how to solve it in c++, in PHP it would be easy.

In the Easteregg controller function getControllerCallbacks I want to return my available callbacks but it won't compile because I can't cast a member function pointer of a derived class to a member function pointer (EastereggController) of the base class (Controller).
I have thought about making the ControllerCallback a "template class" but then I have to know the class of the Controller in the ControllerHandler, which I don't know because i have a std::vector

I'm fairly new to C++, maybe i have overlooked something.

This is my code now:

**Controller.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "Config.h"
#include "Request.h"
#include "ControllerCallback.h"

namespace HttpServer {

class ControllerCallback;

class Controller {
    public:
        Controller();
        virtual std::vector<ControllerCallback> getControllerCallbacks() = 0;

    private:
        Config *config;
        const Request *request;
};
}
#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

**EastereggController.h**

```
#ifndef EASTEREGGCONTROLLER_H
#define EASTEREGGCONTROLLER_H

#include "../HttpServer/Controller.h"

namespace Controller {

    class EastereggController: public HttpServer::Controller  {
        public:
            EastereggController() {};
            std::vector<HttpServer::ControllerCallback> getControllerCallbacks();
            HttpServer::Reply easteregg();
    };
}

#endif // EASTEREGGCONTROLLER_H
```

**EastereggController.cpp**

```
#include "EastereggController.h"

namespace Controller {
    std::vector<HttpServer::ControllerCallback> EastereggController::getControllerCallbacks() {
        std::vector<HttpServer::ControllerCallback> controllerCallbacks;
        HttpServer::ControllerCallback callback;

        callback.pathTemplate = "/easteregg";
        callback.handlerFunctionPtr = &EastereggController::easteregg;
        return controllerCallbacks;
    }

    HttpServer::Reply EastereggController::easteregg() {
        HttpServer::Reply rep;
        rep.content.append("you have found an easteregg\n");
        rep.status = HttpServer::Reply::ok;
        rep.headers.resize(2);
        rep.headers[0].name = "Content-Length";
        rep.headers[0].value = std::to_string(rep.content.size());
        rep.headers[1].name = "Content-Type";
        rep.headers[1].value = "text/plain";
        return rep;
    }
}
```

**ControllerCallback.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLERCALLBACK_H
#define CONTROLLERCALLBACK_H


#include "Reply.h"
#include <string>

namespace HttpServer {

    class Controller;

    class ControllerCallback {

        public:
            ControllerCallback()
                : pathTemplate("") {};
            //,handlerFunctionPtr(nullptr){}

            std::string pathTemplate;
            Reply(Controller::*handlerFunctionPtr)();
    };
}

#endif
```

**ControllerHandler.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLERHANDLER_H
#define CONTROLLERHANDLER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Controller.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "Request.h"
#include "Reply.h"

namespace HttpServer {

    class ControllerHandler {
        public:
            ControllerHandler(Config &conf);
            void registerController(Controller &controller);
            bool invokeController(std::string requestPath, Request &req, Reply &rep);

        private:
            Config &config;
            std::vector<Controller *> controllers;

    };

}

#endif // CONTROLLERHANDLER_H
```

**ControllerHandler.cpp**

```
#include "ControllerHandler.h"
#include "Controller.h"
#include "PathHandler.h"

namespace HttpServer {
    ControllerHandler::ControllerHandler(Config &conf)
        : config(conf) {
    }

    void ControllerHandler::registerController(Controller &controller) {
        controllers.push_back(&controller);
    }

    bool ControllerHandler::invokeController(std::string requestPath, Request &req, Reply &rep) {
        PathHandler pathHandler(requestPath, ':');

        for(Controller *controller : controllers) {
            std::vector<ControllerCallback> callbacks = controller->getControllerCallbacks();
            for(ControllerCallback controllerCallback : callbacks) {
                if(pathHandler.compare(controllerCallback.pathTemplate)) {
                    rep = ((*controller).*(controllerCallback.handlerFunctionPtr))();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think pointer to member function is based on a static offset in the class, which won't work with polymorphic types. You want a virtual function -- pass just a reference/pointer to the object, then call the object's virtual Reply() method.

Comment: so you mean i should  implement the logic where the handler function is found into the class?

Comment: I was just suggesting give it an object and then calling Reply() on that object.  You can still use the same logic to find the right object to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer (which was a syntax error I'll have to admit)

While trying different solutions (before posting here) I had the following snippet:

**EastereggController.cpp**

```
callback.handlerFunctionPtr = reinterpret_cast<HttpServer::Reply HttpServer::Controller::*>(&EastereggController::easteregg);
```

which was syntactilly wrong, but i haven't noticed it because i had the following compile error:

```
error: invalid cast from type 'HttpServer::Reply (Controller::EastereggController::*)()' to type 'HttpServer::Reply HttpServer::Controller::*()'
     callback.handlerFunctionPtr = reinterpret_cast<HttpServer::Reply HttpServer::Controller::*()>(&EastereggController::easteregg);
```

Now the correct version:

```
callback.handlerFunctionPtr = reinterpret_cast<HttpServer::Reply(HttpServer::Controller::*)()>(&EastereggController::easteregg);
```

just added the parentheses and now it works.